# Iterate Over A Collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following classes created:

```
[Serializable]
public class AppContext : IXmlSerializable {
    public string reportType = string.Empty;
    public string entityId = string.Empty;

    // OPTIONS
    public IDictionary<string, OPTIONS> dict_Options = new Dictionary<string, OPTIONS>();
    // Advanced Options
    public List<string> listAdvancedOptions = new List<string>();



    public class OPTIONS {
        public string subjectId = string.Empty;
        public string varNumber = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

How do I iterate over the OPTIONS to get all the varNumbers?

Comment: Iterate over `listAdvancedOptions` or `dict_Options`?

Comment: @chris you have to click the check mark next to an answer to accept it, you've currently accepted none - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: what checkmard?  I only see the up or down arrows.

Comment: Look at the answers - just under the up/down arrows there is a place for you to click on a checkmark to accept an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AppContext.OPTIONS> kvp in appContext.dict_Options)
{
  Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value.varNumber);
}
```

**Method 2**

```
foreach (AppContext.OPTIONS item in appContext.dict_Options.Values)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.varNumber);
}
```

**Method 3**

```
foreach (string item in appContext.dict_Options.Select(x => x.Value.varNumber))
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Dictionary<TKey, TVal>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>>`, so try this:

```
var varNumbers = dict_Options.Select(kvp=>kvp.Value.varNumber);
```

You can also access an IEnumerable of the values of the dictionary directly:

```
var varNumbers = dictOptions.Values.Select(v=>v.varNumber);
```

Comment: What library is Select from?  It says there is no definition for select.

Comment: Select() is part of Linq, accessed by referencing and using System.Linq. It's only available in 3.5 and up, so if you're still using 2.0 I'd consider an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

`OPTIONS` is a class that doesn't implement any collection interface (say `IEnumerable`). You can't iterate over it.

You can iterate over your dictionary - `dict_Options`:

```
foreach(var item in dict_Options)
{
  // use item - say item.varNumber
}
```

Note:

Having public fields in your class is bad design - it violates encapsulation and information hiding and will make it difficult to evolve the class. You should be using private fields and public properties to expose them.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to loop over all of the varNumbers I would probably do the following:

```
        var dict_Options = new Dictionary<string, OPTIONS>();

        foreach (var varNumber in dict_Options.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.varNumber))
        {
            // Your code.
        }
```